# Разместить текст внизу по середине страницы HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, выравнивание

Может быть на этот вопрос есть где-то ответ, но я ничего не нашел.

Я делаю простенький сайт, можно сказать для изучения основ веб-программирования.

Появилось желание сделать что-то типа текста копирайта, типа `(c) CoolPerson - 2020`, и нужно разместить его снизу, по середине страницы как это делают обычно на сайтах.

В гугле искал, текст размещался в снизу в углу, а мне нужно снизу и по середине.

Есть возможность это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим у Вас присутствует несколько блоков, заголовок, основная часть и собственно сам `footer`.

Для того что бы выровнять что либо внутри каждого из этих блоков можно воспользоваться системой [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex):

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.main {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}

.footer .copyright {
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="main">main</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="copyright">Copyright (c) 2020 CoolPerson</div>
</div>
```